# Selecting values <date and >date2 Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select values less than current week and greater than end week. Basically I am trying to get everything that is not in the range made by current and end week --> `(CW,EW)`

The way I went about solving this is

```
df = df[(df['date']<cw)&(df['date']>ew)]
```

I also tried to put `or` instead of `&` but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: df=df[(df['date']<cw)&(df['date']>ew)]

Comment: What's wrong with using df["date"] in between 2 inequalities? Eg cw > df["date"] > ew, which would tell you whether or not you want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or` is not the operator you are looking for.  Try `|` like:

```
df = df[(df['date'] < cw) | (df['date'] > ew)]
```